# How to find out if FFDShow is installed?

Tags: windows-registry, ffdshow, vfw

How can I find out programmatically if [FFDShow](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow-tryout/) is installed?  Is there a registry key I could search for?

Comment: "ffdshow is an advanced DirectShow filter and Video for Windows codec (VFW) codec that supports many audio and video formats." - https://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow-tryout/

Comment: @fixer1234 - I wrote VfW but  SuperUser won't allow me to write it this way. But Anaksunaman was very kind to explain you what VfW is. Even better, do a search for VfW video or VfW codec and you will see millions of results.

Comment: The edit is a "serving suggestion".  Feel free to roll it back if you disagree.  VFW isn't really relevant to the question of whether FFDShow is installed.  The tag isn't defined and has no followers (and is likely to be misused by others in the future).  The FFDShow link will better identify what FFDShow is.

Comment: FFDShow cannot exists without VfW (it is not totally accurate, but you could call it a sub-set of VfW). Anyone searching for FFDshow will also probably interested in VfW. The vice verse is also true.